# Install WCF RIA Services on Windows Server 2016

Tags: wcf, azure, wcf-ria-services, windows-server-2016

I have set an Azure Virtual Machine running Windows Server 2016 and now I need to install WCF RIA Services 1.0 SP2 on it.

Until Windows server 2012 I used to do that via command prompt:

msiexec /j RiaServices.msi SERVER=true

However in 2016 I receive the following message:

"You do not have sufficient privileges to complete the re-advertisement of this product. Re-advertisement requires initiation by a local system account calling the MsiAdvertiseScript API, such as through Group Policy Software Development."

Don't know what does it mean or how to make installation works. Obviously I am running command prompt as Administrator.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem changing the command line to:

```
msiexec /package RiaServices.msi SERVER=true
```

Still not sure exactly why, but the installation succeeded.